# Page with multiple displays on the same path does not respect the different access rights

Tags: views, 9

With Drupal 7, it was possible to define in Views a page with several displays, having all the same URL. By ordering the displays in descending order of access level (Administrator first, Anonymous last), it is possible to have different renderings depending on the role of the logged in user.
This allowed for a single menu entry that displayed only the data to which the user is entitled.
This doesn't seem to work anymore in Drupal 8 and 9.

#### Scenario

create 2 users:
user1 with the profile Content editor
user2 with the authenticated user profile
[image]

Create a view _test

duplicate the display

rename first display and set role access (for this display only)

[image]

rename second display and set role access (for this display only)

[image]

Login as user1 and go to /test
The view is correctly displayed (title view is Edit as specified in view definition)

[image]

Logout and login as user2 and go to /test

[image]

Logout, login as admin ans disable display *Page user1*, save and logout/login as user2
the view is displayed

[image]

How is it possible to have the same behavior as in Drupal 7?